# Automatic inputs in Chromium are filled randomly

Tags: chromium, barcode-scanner, hid, pyautogui, evdev

Automatic inputs in Chromium are filled randomly

**CASE**

I want to simulate a barcode scanner without any hardware attached to my computer. From what I learnt, barcode scanners behave as keyboards, so I want to simulate a keyboard HID device.

**ENVIRONMENT**

Chromium version 53.0.2785.143 Built on Ubuntu , running on LinuxMint 17.2 (64-bit)

**ATTEMPTS**

**1)** evdev in python

**2)** write into dev/input/event* using C++

**3)** pyautogui

Attempts 1 and 2 behave similarly. Both try to write into dev/input/event* file which corresponds to computer keyboard. But for multiple keypress in loop, the result is not what I expect: if I simulate a keypress repetition, the result goes randomly. Furthermore, some keyboard keys start printing another character which does not correspond to them until the terminal is closed.

So I went with attempt 3 which prints what I want, but the result goes randomly in Chromium.

**PROBLEM**

pyautogui works in Firefox, but writes randomly inputs in Chromium. It looks like Chromium are avoiding automatic input in its input forms in any website.

**Python program:**

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.typewrite('1234567890123\n', interval=0)
```

**Example**

It prints 1234567890123 in Firefox;

It prints 2413123098765 in Chromium. #Random number of 13 digits

**QUESTION**

Does anybody know why Chromium behaves like that?